# JQuery get text from :nth selector from dynamic table

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-selectors

I have an issue which I cannot figure out and have found some help, but not the help I'm needing.

I need to access the `data[i].no` variable from the row that is clicked.  I just can't get my code at the bottom to display this.

Here's the code that creates a dynamic table from a JSON query:

```
html = '<table class="tbl small">'
$time = 0
for (var i = 0; i< len; i++) {          
    $time = (parseInt($time)+parseInt(data[i].time));
    if (data[i].status == "MISSING") {
    $('#tottime').html('');
    } else {
        $('#tottime').html('Total time outstanding for ' + monthNames[d.getMonth()] + ' : ' + $time);
    }
    if (data[i].overdue == "Yes") {
        html = html + '<tr style="background: #FF0000">'
    } else if (data[i].status == "RE ASSES") {
        html = html + '<tr style="background: #D0C0C0">'
    } else if (data[i].status == "REPAIR") {
        html = html + '<tr style="font-style: italic">'
    } else{
        html = html + '<tr>'
    }
    html = html + '<td class="border col1">'+data[i].line+'</td>'
    html = html + '<td class="border col2">'+data[i].no+'</td>'
    html = html + '<td class="border col3">'+data[i].desc+'</td>'           
    html = html + '<td class="border col4">'+data[i].loc+'</td>'            
    html = html + '<td class="border col5">'+data[i].time+'</td>'           
    html = html + '<td class="border col6">'+data[i].lastcal+'</td>'            
    html = html + '<td class="border col7">'+data[i].frequency+'</td>'          
    html = html + '<td class="border col8">'+data[i].status+'</td>' 
    if (data[i].external == "E" ) {
        html = html + '<td class="border col9">&#10004;</td>'   
    } else {
        html = html + '<td class="border col9"></td>'
    }
    html = html + '</tr>'           
    }
html = html + '</table>'
$('#output').html(html);
```

And here's the code creating a dialog to show a confirmation page:

```
$('#output').on('click','td',function() {
    html = $(':nth-child(2)',this).text()
    $('#msgBox').html(html);
    $('#msgBox').dialog('option','title','Calibration Complete')
    $('#msgBox').dialog('open')
})
```

Comment: What is the result or error you are getting?

Comment: Your `#output` only has one child: your `<table>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the click event `this` is the clicked `td` and you want to search the second `td`, you should move "up" to the `tr` first.

```
$('#output').on('click','td',function() {

    // $(this) is the clicked td
    // .closest("tr") returns the first tr parent ( in this case the same as .parent() )
    // .find(':nth-child(2)') gives you the second child of the tr
    var html = $(this).closest('tr').find(':nth-child(2)').text()

    $('#msgBox').html(html);
    $('#msgBox').dialog('option','title','Calibration Complete')
    $('#msgBox').dialog('open')
})
```

Also (in a completely different area), try to give your a variables a scope instead of using global variables. This could save you a lot of trouble and you only need to add `var` before the first use (like above).

Comment: Many thanks, this adds to the learning journey with JQuery.  Works perfectly, thank you for your invaluable assistance!

Comment: alternatively you could have used var html = $(this).parent().find(':nth-child(2)').text()

Comment: @Taff, yes, as I said in the comments above the line, in this case `closest("tr")` and `parent()` are the same. I personally prefer `closest` because: #1 the selector clarifies what the result will be and #2 when its not a table you reduce the code's dependence to the markup